# Update query only updating Holliday entry when an entry exists

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write an update query to populate an error field in the time sheet table when a user doesn't enter a code of H on a Holliday

The query needs to look at one weeks worth of data from time sheet and if no entry is found for a holliday or if an entry is found but without a code of H. Multiple entries on a holliday day are ok as long as 1 of them has an H code. If no H code is found I need to add a Y to the error column in time detail for every entry in time detail for the week

The week and account will be parameters

```
Table  Time Sheet Fields account hours code date error
Table Hollidays Fields date
```

This is a sample of what I need to happen

Sample Data

```
date,code,account,error
8/1/2012    R    12345 null
8/5/2012    R    12345 null
8/9/2012    H    12345 null
```

all 3 of these records error fields turn to No

Sample Data

```
date,code,account,error
8/1/2012    R    12345 null
8/5/2012    R    12345 null
8/9/2012    R    12345 null
```

all 3 of these records error fields turn to Yes

Sample Data

```
date,code,account,error
8/1/2012    R    12345 null
8/5/2012    R    12345 null
8/9/2012    H    12345 null
8/9/2012    R    12345 null
```

all 3 of these records error fields turn to No

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you want:

```
UPDATE ts
set error = 'Y'
FROM timesheet ts
left join holiday h
  on ts.tsdate between DateAdd(Day, -7, h.hdate) 
    and dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, h.hdate), 0)
WHERE ts.tsdate > DateAdd(Day, -7, getdate())
  AND ts.tsdate <= dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, getdate()), 0)
  and h.hdate is not null
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f94b2/4)

Edit, based on your comments I think you want this:

```
UPDATE ts
set error = CASE when h.hdate Is not null then 'H' ELSE 'R' END
FROM timesheet ts
left join holiday h
  on ts.tsdate between DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, h.hdate)-1), h.hdate)
    and DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, h.hdate)), h.hdate)
WHERE ts.tsdate > DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, getdate())-1), getdate())
  AND ts.tsdate <= DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, getdate())), getdate())
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f94b2/13)

This second version gets the start/end of the week (sample is Sun-Sat) and verifies that there is a holiday in those dates and then that the timesheet date is also in that same week.  If the holiday day is not null then the record with be updated with `'H'` otherwise the records in that week will get an `'R'`.

Comment: @user1345246 please edit your OP with what you have tried.  This seems to be working on the Fiddle I provided.

Comment: code field should be set to either H or R. Since the holliday you entered was on 8/9 and no entry exists for that day with a code H all the other records should be set to an error

Comment: Sample Data

date,code,account,error
8/1/2012    R    12345 null
8/5/2012    R    12345 null
8/9/2012    H    12345 null

all 3 of these records error fields turn to No


Sample Data

date,code,account,error
8/1/2012    R    12345 null
8/5/2012    R    12345 null
8/9/2012    R    12345 null

all 3 of these records error fields turn to Yes

Sample Data

date,code,account,error
8/1/2012    R    12345 null
8/5/2012    R    12345 null
8/9/2012    H    12345 null
8/9/2012    R    12345 null

all 3 of these records error fields turn to No

Comment: you can't post that in the comments, you need to edit your original question and post data there

Comment: Im so sorry to be a pain but the codes do not get updated. The only thing that gets updated is the error field. all records for the week will get updated with a Y or N in the errors column even if no timesheet data exists for the holliday day. You will update with a N if a holliday record exists with a code H. If no data exists on the holliday or if data exists and it is not code H then all the records for the week get a Y for the error field

Comment: @user1345246 based on the sample data what is the holiday date?

Comment: 8/9/2012 is the holliday date